# sequence doesn't exist ORA-02289

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem getting my SEQUENCE. 
I have created a sequence as administrator and have grant select and alter privileges to the other user.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "OWNER"."TOT_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1000 MAXVALUE 1000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;

grant select,ALTER on TOT_SEQ to user;
commit;
```

When I do this :

```
select sequence_name from all_sequences;

TOT_SEQ
```

I can see my SEQUENCE in the list.

But I can't access the sequence in my code. using :

```
select <SEQUNCE_name>.nextval from dual;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: select system.TOT_SEQ.nextval from dual

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but you don't need the commit here. DDL automatically performs a commit before and after each statement.

Comment: Yes I know I don't have to commit. But can't help it. I thought I might me missing something as obvious as COMMIT:(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will either have to fully qualify your sequence via:

```
SELECT <owner>.<sequence name>.nextval FROM dual;
```

Or create a public synonym for it:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM TOT_SEQ for OWNER.TOT_SEQ;
SELECT TOT_SEQ.nexval FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: And Sorry I don't have permissions to do this either :(

Comment: Then you will have to fully qualify your sequence name by adding the sequence owner to it. But you said that above did not work, can you share the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 17 in 'select OWNER.<*>TOT_SEQ.nextval from DUAL') [for Statement "select OWNER.TOT_SEQ.nextval from DUAL"]

Comment: Are you sure you are connected with the same user that created the sequence? In your example above you have `grant select,ALTER on TOT_SEQ to user;` which means that the currently connected user will receive the grant.

Comment: I am sure! I am looking in the right DB. After refreshing my SQL DEVELOPER and multiple commits I Can now get the nextval on command line and in my SQL DEVELOPER. But still my script would find the sequence :(

Comment: But are you also using the right user? I would replace the `user` bit in `grant select,ALTER on TOT_SEQ to user` with the actual user who is connecting in your script, e.g. GVENZL: `grant select,ALTER on TOT_SEQ to GVENZL`

Comment: Hey all, Thanks for the help. Creating a SYNONYM Solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you create the sequence in uppercase, even if you use lower case in trigger / select statement.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the fully qualified name in your code?

```
select <owner>.<SEQUNCE_name>.nextval from dual;
```

If you already have, can you edit the question to post the output of the following commands. The "OWNER", "USER" in your examples are a bit confusing.

select sequence, owner from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'TOT_SEQ';
select grantor, table_name, privilege from all_tab_privs where sequence_name = 'TOT_SEQ';

Comment: YES I Did. And that didn't help as well. Sorry I didn't add them in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the priviliges of the schema which you are using. Also verify by putting schema name in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As it is unable to find the sequence from the table. So, create public SYNONYM for the sequence by which SYS will have the privilege's to access the sequence next value. your problem will be solve, So does mine.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726573/sequence-doesnt-exist-ora-02289/25726744#25726744) also states: _create a public synonym for it_. So how is your answer different to the accepted answer?